# I am having an issue when trying to call the "calculateTotalPrice" method back into the main method to compute the final pricing

Tags: java, arrays, syntax-error

I've written the following program and am having an issue when trying to call the "calculateTotalPrice" method back into the main method to compute the final pricing. I'm not sure if it is an error with my method or my call. Main works as desired without the call to the "calculateTotalPrice" method. Can anyone give any suggestions as to how I should rearrange the secondary method or call statement? Thanks

```
public class GrapefruitOrderingArray {

//Declare Constants 
public static final int SIZE = 100;


/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Declare Variables
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);     //Input new scanner system
String CustomerName;                         //Declare customer's name as a string 
int nNumber = 0;                             //Declare integer variable for nNumber
int nProducts = 0;                           //Declare integer variable for nproducts
int nTotal;                                  //Declare integer variable for ntotal
double[] nFinalPrice = new double [SIZE];
int [] itemPrices = {49,299,329,399,199,1299,1199,999,599};      //Declare integer variable array
int nCount = 0;

//Declare Constants 
final int SENTINEL = 10;
final double SALES_TAX = 0.065;

//Prompt user to enter name
System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");

//Enter user name
CustomerName = input.nextLine();

//Print Blank Line 
System.out.println("");

//Begin Product Listing Declarations with respect to array above
System.out.println("GRAPEFRUIT PRODUCT:");

System.out.println("1. gPod shuffle $" + itemPrices[0]);

System.out.println("2. gPod Touch   $" + itemPrices[1]);

System.out.println("3. gPad Mini    $" + itemPrices[2]);

System.out.println("4. gPad 2       $" + itemPrices[3]);

System.out.println("5. gPhone       $" + itemPrices[4]);

System.out.println("6. gMac         $" + itemPrices[5]);

System.out.println("7. MacNovel Pro $" + itemPrices[6]);

System.out.println("8. MacNovel Air $" + itemPrices[7]);

System.out.println("9. MiniMac      $" + itemPrices[8]);

System.out.println("10. Complete my order");

// Keep reading until the input is 10
System.out.println("\nPlease select an item from the menu above: ");

//Begin while-loop statement
while (nNumber != SENTINEL) {
 //Read number entered by the user
 nNumber = input.nextInt();

 if (nNumber == SENTINEL) {   
 System.out.println("Thank you for ordering with Grapefruit Company, " + CustomerName);

 break;
} 
//Call final price calculation
nFinalPrice = calculateTotalPrice(nNumber); 

//If desired the user may select another or multiple products now    
System.out.println("\nPlease select another item from the menu above: ");
}  
    //Print blank line to screen
    System.out.println("");

    //Total amount of product ordered
    System.out.println("Total items ordered: " + nProducts );

    //Total price of items ordered
    System.out.println("Price of items ordered: $" + nTotal );

    //Sales tax associated with the purchase
    System.out.println("Sales tax: $" + SALES_TAX * nTotal );

    //Total amount due by the customer to Grapefruit Co. 
    System.out.println("Total amount due: $" + (SALES_TAX * nTotal + nTotal));

   }
 } //End main method

/**
* This method calculates the total price of the products ordered
* @param itemPrice     Individualized product prices
* @param nProduct          Total price of items paid for
* @return nTotals      Returns the number of the product associated with it's initialized price
*/
private static double[] calculateTotalPrice(int nNumber) {

//Calculate entered items
nTotal = nTotal + itemPrices [nNumber-1];

//Increment the total number of products entered    
 nProducts++;

 return nNumber;

 } //end method calculateTotalPriceOfItemsOrdered 
} //end class calculateTotalPriceOfItemsOrdered
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  Error messages?

Comment: "am having an issue" is *never* enough information. Does it fail at compile-time? Does it throw an exception? Does it give you back the wrong answer?

Comment: Sorry for the broad scope.. At my method call on line 85 it is giving me "cannot find symbol" syntax errors for all four variables. Also from line 115-136, which is "calculateTotalPrice" method, it is giving me syntax error 'class, interface, or enum expected'? Basically my program compiles fine without the additional method and if I store my calculations in main but I have to have an additional method which stores the calculations and call them back into main.

Comment: @dcaswell Updated..  Still getting an error for "class, interface, or enum expected" in lines 118-130 and an error for my nFinalPrice method call.. Here is my complete code, can someone edit it or explain to me what's going wrong?

Comment: @jzd line 85 is not initializing the method call and lines 115-130 are giving me syntax errors for expected class, etc.. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

- `int nTotal =0;`   Happens after `int nTotal` is taken in as a parameter.
- `SIZE` isn't declared anywhere.
- More of a side note, but your comments are overly excessive.

Comment: SIZE is declared to 100 outside of the main method block as a final global parameter, I just didn't include it into the code I posted here.. Sorry about the comments, it's a project I'm working on and the pseudocode has to be included within the program. I'm having issues with my calculateTotalPrice method from lines 116-136 and the method call in main on line 85. If you remove the method call and calculateTotalPrice method it compiles perfectly, but, I must include an alternate method that stores the calculations in it.

Answer (score 0):

This program returns the total price of the items selected by a customer. Hope it will help you.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CalTotalPrice {
    static int totalPrice=0;
    static int [] itemPrices = {49,299,329,399,199,1299,1199,999,599};  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     

        //declaring variables
        String CustomerName;                                                        
        int itemNumber = 0;                                                  
        int noOfProducts = 0;


        final int SENTINEL = 10;
        final double SALES_TAX = 0.065;

        //Getting customer name
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        CustomerName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");

        //Begin Product Listing Declarations with respect to array above
        System.out.println("GRAPEFRUIT PRODUCT:");
        System.out.println("1. gPod shuffle $" + itemPrices[0]);
        System.out.println("2. gPod Touch   $" + itemPrices[1]);
        System.out.println("3. gPad Mini    $" + itemPrices[2]);
        System.out.println("4. gPad 2       $" + itemPrices[3]);
        System.out.println("5. gPhone       $" + itemPrices[4]);
        System.out.println("6. gMac         $" + itemPrices[5]);
        System.out.println("7. MacNovel Pro $" + itemPrices[6]);
        System.out.println("8. MacNovel Air $" + itemPrices[7]);
        System.out.println("9. MiniMac      $" + itemPrices[8]);
        System.out.println("10. Complete my order");
        System.out.print("\nPlease select an item from the menu above: ");

        while (itemNumber != SENTINEL) {
            itemNumber = input.nextInt();

            if (itemNumber <= SENTINEL) {   
                System.out.println("Thank you for ordering with Grapefruit Company, " + CustomerName);
                break;
            } 

            noOfProducts++; //increse number of products ordered
            totalPrice= calculateTotalPrice(itemNumber);    
            System.out.print("\nPlease select another item from the menu above: ");
        }  

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Total items ordered: " + noOfProducts);
                System.out.println("Price of items ordered: $" +totalPrice);
                System.out.println("Sales tax: $" + SALES_TAX *totalPrice);
                System.out.println("Total amount due: $" + (SALES_TAX *totalPrice+totalPrice));

    }


    public static int calculateTotalPrice(int itemNumber) {

        totalPrice=totalPrice+ itemPrices[itemNumber-1];
        return totalPrice;

    }

}
```

Comment: It is compiling in the same way mine does with a syntax error for a class expected.. I posted my full code that I have written, can you review that to make changes?